# What is the syntax in serverless yml file to deploy lambda to multiple regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a requirement to deploy my lambda artifact to 3 different regions. I am using serverless framework. 
My .yml file looks like this:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs4.3
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
```

Comment: I have one doubt, since the answer you accepted implies we don't have to do anything with serverless.yml file, so what is the use of defining only one region in this file, i.e, us-east-1 in your example. Do we need to define other regions here as well, if yes can you show how?

Comment: region can be specified through the yaml or cli arg. cli takes precedence. If not given anywhere then serverless will throw an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK it's impossible to configure deployment to multiple regions via `serverless.yml`. However, you can do it [via the cli](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/deploy#deployment-with-stage-and-region-options), one region at a time:

```
serverless deploy --stage production --region eu-central-1
serverless deploy --stage production --region eu-west-1
...
```

You may want to automate it using your own script, implement it as a [plugin](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/plugins#writing-plugins), or submit a [feature proposal](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/new).